# Split pandas column by separator for different string sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can one split a column like `df.value`

```
value
--------
Top/Animals/Cat
Top/Dog
Pig/Guineea/Piglet
```

into multiple columns

```
val1 |   val2   | val3 |
Top    Animals     Cat
NaN      Top       Dog
Pig    Guineea    Piglet
```

such that I have the number of columns of the longest string and NaN where other strings are not the same length?

Comment: So you need to fill NaN at the start of the string? 
Value `Top` Will be 'NaN Nan Top` right?

Comment: Hi @Poojan, yep, Top will be Nan  Nan Top

Comment: Omg someone woke the ninjas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try something new

```
sep='/'
s=df.value.str.count(sep)
s=((s.max()-s).map(lambda x : x*sep)+df.value).str.split(sep,expand=True)
     0        1       2
0  Top  Animals     Cat
1           Top     Dog
2  Pig  Guineea  Piglet
```

Answer (score 1):

`.str.split()`'s `expand=True` is your friend here!

```py
df['value'].str.split('/', expand=True)
```

Comment: Oh sorry misread, `None` values are right filled now not left.

Comment: This puts nan in last column

Answer (score 0):

- You can first reverse the order of string and then use `str.split` with `expand` parameter

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'value' : ['Top/Animals/Cat', 'Top/Dog', 'Pig/Guineea/Piglet', 'Top']})

# reverse string first. Top/Animals/Cat will become Cat/Animals/
df = df['value'].apply(lambda x : '/'.join(x.split('/')[::-1])).str.split('/', expand=True) 

# column renaming and order
df.columns = ['val' + str(i) for i in range(len(df.columns), 0,-1)]
df = df[df.columns[::-1]]
df
```

output

```
    val1    val2    val3
0   Top     Animals Cat
1   None    Top     Dog
2   Pig     Guineea Piglet
3   None    None    Top
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataFrame constructor to build the columns in reverse order, then reindex them:

```
resul = pd.DataFrame([reversed(i) for i in df['value'].str.split('/')])
resul = resul.reindex(reversed(resul.columns), axis=1)
resul.columns = ['val' + str(i+1) for i in range(len(resul.columns))]
```

It gives as expected:

```
   val1     val2    val3
0   Top  Animals     Cat
1  None      Top     Dog
2   Pig  Guineea  Piglet
```

Comment: Looks good, how can I apply this if 'value' is only one column of df, and df has another column I want to keep intact?

Answer (score 0):

This solution returns NaN and not None (as requested by the OP)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"c1": ["Top/Animals/Cat",
                          "Top/Dog", 
                          "Pig/Guineea/Piglet"]})
df["c1"] = df["c1"].str.split("/")
c1_max_len = df["c1"].map(len).max()
df["c1"] = df["c1"].map(lambda x: (c1_max_len - len(x)) * [np.nan] + x)
df_exploded = pd.DataFrame(df.c1.values.tolist(), index= df.index)
```